# In OS X, C++ unhandled exceptions do not automatically print output of what()

Tags: c++, macos, exception

Take this bit of code:

```
#include <exception>

int main()
{
    throw std::exception();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this with gcc in Ubuntu Linux, I get the following helpful output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::exception'
what():  std::exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

However, when compiled and run on OS X Mountain Lion (with both GCC and clang) I get the following, far less helpful output:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Is there a way to make OS X default to printing the output of what() on an unhandled exception?

Comment: Not much help but it appears that on Lion compiling in debug mode (g++) would do what you want, so I'm wondering if Apple has helpfully redirected these things. It seems like it generates a debug log in Console under User Diagnostic Reports.

Comment: Catch it and print the message. Unhandled exceptions are design errors.

Comment: You could use diagnostic information from Boost: try { .... } catch(...) { std::cout << boost::current_exception_diagnostic_information(); }

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this worked for me in OS X Mavericks:

```
$ echo '
> #include <stdexcept>
>
> int main()
> {
>     throw std::runtime_error("oh no");
>     return 0;
> }
> ' | g++ -x c++ - ; ./a.out
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: oh no    
Abort trap: 6
```

So I guess Apple just got around to fixing that for you.

Edit:
Also, I don't know why I didn't test your example, too, but that works as well:

From g++ / clang:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::exception: std::exception
Abort trap: 6
```